# Object created multiple times on parse everytime the project is simulated

Tags: ios, parse-platform

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
PFObject *Event = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Event1"];

Event[@"EventName"] = @"Wine Tasting Event";
Event[@"City"] = @"Newyork";

[Event saveInBackground];

_EventName = Event[@"EventName"];
_City = Event[@"City"];
NSLog(@"%@ is happening in %@",_EventName,_City);
```

}

I have been trying to create parse object 'Event1' to test some data. But when I run the project and refresh core on parse, same rows are created multiple times with differenct objectID. How do I stop this?

[image]

Comment: By deleting all of the code that explicitly does that. What is it that you are trying to do? Because going by your code, you're trying to create a new wine tasting event every time you load this view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your code explicitly creates and saves a new object every time.

It could be that you manually create the data on the server and add the object id to your code, you can then create the object in the code with no data and the object id (`objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:`) and use `fetch` to download the details.

Otherwise you need to run a query to check if the data already exists on the server and create it if not (though you may still get odd duplicates).